# Sql Server 2008 missing parameter error c# code-behind

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sql Server 2008 says the `@event_id` parameter is missing, but I've confirmed it has a value.

I've tested the `usp_get_it_alert_members` stored procedure with the same `event_id` and it returns the correct value.

Can anyone recommend some additional steps for troubleshooting?

```
try
{
   Int32 event_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["event_id"].ToString());

   using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())){
       cnn.Open();

       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_get_it_alert_members", cnn)){
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event_id", event_id);

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
           while (rdr.Read()){
               ...
           }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) to be StoredProcedure.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I was going insane.